# subsonic 3 scaffolding

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Are there the asp.net scaffolding controls (ex: < subsonic:QuickTable />) still available in subsonic 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - we did that the best we could with 2.2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Not Subsonic related, but Dynamic Data is something you might want to look into.

[Dynamic Data Information](http://www.asp.net/(S(y3u2uc45kakrr555dijiwvf2))/DynamicData/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no more scaffolding feature anymore.  Subcommander also is abandoned.