# How to use Scaffoling from SS2 in SubSonic 3.0?

Tags: activerecord, subsonic3, scaffolding

I just started using SubSonic ver 3.0 and I am not able to find sufficient info on the scaffolding feature. I understand scaffolding is included in version 2.x but can be used with 3.x also.
My question is, what do I have to include in my SunSonic 3.x ActiveRecord project, what to reference and what to add to the web.config / App.config to be able to use the scaffolding feature in SubSonic Version 3.x.
An example would be nice.

Thanks for your help.
gm

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082667/subsonic-3-scaffolding

Comment: Thanks for the link, I saw this comment before. However, all it say's is that you can use the version 2.x scaffolding in version 3.x, it does not tell me how.
Thanks anyway.
gm

Comment: There is no Scaffolding feature in the version 3.  This is the sense of the Rob's answer.  Precisely the templates philosophy is that: well, there is no such feature: done it by yourself.  You might remember that many features were abandoned, by example the excelent Subcommander, and also scaffolding.